# jQuery position, can percents be used?

Tags: jquery

If I use the position property can I use a percent or am I stuck with just pixels?

I have to edit a small piece of code (not my code) and currently it is...

```
    if( pos.left >= 600)
        {
            clear();
            right();
            $(this).next('div').removeClass('to_right');
            $(this).next('div').removeClass('to_left');
            $(this).next('div').addClass('to_left');
```

Right now its saying if the left edge of my slider is 600 from the left side of the browser, but what I need is if the slider is 50% away from left of browser. This way if the screen is resized the slider always responds accordingly.

This is using jQuery 1.6.0, not sure if newer versions allow for percent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the math yourself:

```
var pct = 50; // percent
if (pos.left >= $(window).width() * pct/100) {
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thanks. So....... excuse my newbness, can I just put those two lines as a replacement for if(pos.left...)?

Comment: Should be all you need. If you want to change it to 45%, just alter the `pct` variable.

Comment: Worked flawlessly and I learned something new. Digital high five for you sir. Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following jQuery syntax to get the value of the element left property (if it was specified in % in CSS):

```
var _left=$({yourElement}).css("left");
```